Fill the interior of an SVG path
I am attempting to fill the interior of  a path element in SVG using the following HTML code:
I have seen several related posts on SO but I have found them incomprehensible and of no help. What do I have to do to fill the interior of the path element with a color?


<h2>Start of arrow</h2>

  <svg width="450" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="arrow" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="green">
      <path d="M100 298 Q 300 306 400 290"/>
      <path d="M100 315 Q 300 305 400 315"/>
      <path d="M100 298 Q 112 306 100 315"/>
    </g>
  </svg>




use one path, not 3 paths.

@Robert Longson I tried this without success. I find it much easier to both read and write SVG with one path element per path segment.

Sure but it's much harder/impossible to fill it, which is what you want isn't it? Anyway if you want to draw something using SVG and you don't know how, simply draw it with an SVG editor such as Inkscape

@Robert Langson I have tried several editors including Inkscape and havee found them very difficult to use. They all assume much more general graphics knowledge than I have.

Ease of using Inkscape 95/100. Ease of hand editing SVG 3/100.

TL;DR: you need a reasonable drawing/coordinate order (GUI or markup)
One approach to draw a filled path is to abstract the path data to a polygon and sort command coordinates in a suitable order:
(re-ordering path commands requires your path commands to use absolute coordinates – an exception are H and V commands describing only x or y coordinates)

Concatenate path data – as specified by the d attribute
Path commands to polygon (strip all command tokens after M like Q )
Remove redundant adjacent command coordinates
Add Q command tokens to interpret certain vertices as quadratic Bézier control points (defining the curvature)



body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
<h3>1. Concatenated path commands to polygon – gibberish :(</h3>
<p>Strip Command type letters. Third path should become 2nd command. Whitespace agnostic. </p>
<svg viewBox="0 200 450 200">
  <path stroke="red" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" d="
             M 100,298  300,306  400,290
             100,315  300,305  400,315
             100,298  112,306  100,315" />
</svg>

<h3>2. Path commands to polygon – sort points by logical drawing order (top-right to bottom-right)</h3>
<svg viewBox="0 200 450 200">
  <!-- 
    1. path1: quadratic command end point to start/moveTo 
    2. path1: Moveto to quadratic final point
    3. path3: to 2nd segment
    4. path2: to 3rd segment
    -->
  <path stroke="red" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" d="
             M 
             400,290  300,306  100,298
             100,298  112,306  100,315
             100,315  300,305  400,315
             " />
</svg>

<h3>3. Path commands to polygon – remove redundant adjacent coordinates</h3>
<svg viewBox="0 200 450 200">
  <path stroke="red" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" d="
             M 400,290  300,306  100,298
             112,306  100,315
             300,305  400,315
             " />
</svg>


<h3>4. Path polygon to quadratic Béziercontrol points</h3>
<svg viewBox="0 200 450 200">
  <path stroke="red" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" fill="red" d="
             M 
             400,290  Q 300,306  100,298
             Q 112,306  100,315
             Q 300,305  400,315
             z
             " />
</svg>



SVG Markup readability:

SVG path data attributes are white-space agnostic – so you can easily add line breaks or tab indentations to improve readability for development
you can also use different separators like , to group x/y coordinate pairs if it helps readability

GUI (graphic application) vs. SVG markup

A basic knowledge of a GUI-driven vector editor like Inkscape is just incredibly helpful – apart from data-driven so dynamically generated visualizations (charts, graphs etc) other complex vector graphics (fonts, icons, logos etc) are usually created with a graphic app and then exported to SVG (and optimized/fine-tuned code-wise).
basic knowledge of SVG path data commands is also helpful – but: if you can achieve your tasks faster and more accurately with a GUI – that's perfectly fine!
a more profound understanding is mainly required if you need to write a library/script for dynamic SVG creation (e.g the aforementioned data visualization) parsing or manipulation

Further reading

mdn docs
CSS-tricks: The SVG path Syntax: An Illustrated Guide
W3C SVG2 working draft spec: path grammar

